# Rubber ducky script that runs an application on the plugged in rubber ducky?

Tags: windows

I've created a exe file that when run temporaily overrides key inputs and esentialy remaps keys while the script is running to the Dvorak keyboard layout. Now I could just manually click on the application when its plugged into any windows comuputer, but wheres the fun in that? i'm wondering if there is a rubber ducky script that will bypass the annoying stuff and automatically run my exe file when plugged into any computer. This will make working with other computers a breeze since im learning the Dvorak layout.

```
                             ‎
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.